# Thales HSM generate pinblock in thales format 05(ISO 9564-1 Format 1) without pan and encrypt it with zpk

Tags: security, hsm

How to generate pinblock in thales format 05(ISO 9564-1 Format 1) without PAN and encrypt it with ZPK, this format does't requite PAN but i can't find way to do it without it in documentation (http://www.pay-logic.com/docs/hostcommandv23b.pdf)

Comment: I have answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438642/zpk-encryption-iso-format-9594-1-format-0/45475189#45475189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you still need to provide PAN (12 digits) in the command but it's not used, so you may use e.g. 12 zeros.